# How to make unsorted MapSet?

Tags: elixir

Is it possible to create MapSet unsorted?

how it works:

```
iex(1)> MapSet.new([2,3,2,1])
#MapSet<[1, 2, 3]>
```

how expected:

```
iex(1)> MapSet.new([2,3,2,1])
#MapSet<[2, 3, 1]>
```

Comment: What is your use case exactly? Are you trying to leverage MapSet as a way of randomizing a list with unique values?

Comment: yes, but still want have properties of set, like intersection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MapSet`s aren't sorted at all. You might see that the values appear sorted for small maps, but that's an implementation detail of how Erlang handles small maps and `MapSet` uses a map internally.

If you want to get a list of unique elements back, you can instead use `Enum.reduce` + a `MapSet` like this:

```
defmodule A do
  def sorted_uniq(list) do
    Enum.reduce(list, {[], MapSet.new}, fn x, {list, map_set} ->
      if MapSet.member?(map_set, x) do
        {list, map_set}
      else
        {[x | list], MapSet.put(map_set, x)}
      end
    end)
    |> elem(0)
    |> Enum.reverse
  end
end

IO.inspect A.sorted_uniq([2, 3, 2, 1])
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Whats the point of even using a MapSet then?  There isn't an applicable way to use the MapSet functions like union and intersect.